# Что влияет на скорость выполнения запроса?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

**Используется:
    Комп:** 
       - 2,6Ггц
       - 6,0 Гб ОЗУ
       - Win 7x64

**Программы:**
        - OpenServer
        - Access - 2016
        - MySql 5.7 x 64
        - Odbc - mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.7-winx64

Всё установлено и используется на одном компьютере

**Характеристики таблицы:**
- кол строк предполагается  - больше 1,0 млн
- количество столбцов ~ 20 штук

Таблица  (tbl8)
 Кол. строк  - 12 425 строк
 Объём  - 24,6 Мб

```
        CREATE TABLE `tbl5` (
        `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `tbl` LONGTEXT NULL,
        `idsub` INT(20) NOT NULL,
        `pol_3` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        `pol_4` LONGTEXT NULL,
        `pol_5` LONGTEXT NULL,
        `pol_6` LONGTEXT NULL,
        `pol_7` LONGTEXT NULL,
        `pol_8` LONGTEXT NULL,
        `pol_9` LONGTEXT NULL,
        `pol_10` LONGTEXT NULL,
        `pol_11` LONGTEXT NULL,
        `pol_12` LONGTEXT NULL,
        `pol_13` LONGTEXT NULL,
        `pol_14` LONGTEXT NULL,
        `pol_15` LONGTEXT NULL,
        `pol_16` LONGTEXT NULL,
        `pol_17` LONGTEXT NULL,
        UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`)
    )
    COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT=240013
    ;
```

В таблице тип полей "LONGTEXT" принят как предварительный, для проверки работы базы... Потом полям будут присвоены необходимые типы: LONGTEXT, TEXT, числа, даты и т.д. В полях: pol_9, pol_10, pol_11 используется много строчный текст более 1 000 символов. В остальных полях просто текст "ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_n"

**Запрос**
    Выполняем запрос в программе HeidiSql из таблицы tbl8

```
select*
    from
        `01tst`.`tbl8`
    where
        (
            `01tst`.`tbl8`.`idsub` = 2
        )
```

Запрос выполняется  2 сек.
Когда количество строк достигает более 100 000 - длительность выполнения запроса 40 сек.

**Вопрос**
Как уменьшить длительность выполнения запроса?
Что влияет на длительность выполнения запроса?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Например, попробовать индексировать не по `UNIQUE`, а по `PRIMARY`

Comment: В любых вопросах по скорости работы необходимо приводить план выполнения, полученный (для MySQL) с помощью explain. А вообще при таком времени выполнения похоже что у вас нет индекса на колонку idsub и оно вынуждено перебирать всю таблицу

Comment: я для начала попробовал бы создать индекс для `idsub`. Так как по нему происходит фильтрация, может сильно помочь

Comment: Почему `id` не `primary key`? И нет индекса по `id_sub`.

Answer (score 1):

Добавь индекс к полю idsub. 
Изучите, что такое индексы [1](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/MySQL_indexes.html)  [2](https://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0+%D1%81+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8+%D0%B2+MySQL)
Так же не плохо было бы знать про EXPLAIN [1](https://habrahabr.ru/post/31129/)